# How can I kill only one item frame instead of all of them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried using `/kill @e[type=item_frame]`. However, it kills every item frame. So my question is, how can I kill only one item frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a scoreboard tag to the item frame when you spawn it in, so your kill function looks like this:

`kill @e[type=item_frame,tag=killable]`

with killable being the tag. If a player is running the command/you aren't spawning it in you can kill one within a certain radius:

`kill @e[type=item_frame,distance=..1]`

which will kill any item frames within one block.

Edit: I saw your other question and here's the summon command you would use:

`summon minecraft:item_frame -1242 58 219 {Facing:2,Tags["killable"]}`

Edit 2:
I just remembered that a tag is not unique: if you have multiple entities tagged as 'killable' it will kill all of them. Instead, use a customName:

`summon minecraft:item_frame -1242 58 219 {Facing:2,CustomName:"killableFrame"}`

`kill @e[name=killableFrame]`

Comment: Thanks Nik3141 but there is a problem if i summon an item frame using the command ```/summon minecraft:item_frame -1242 58 219 {Facing:2,CustomName:"killableFrame"}``` when i do : ```kill @e[name=killableFrame]``` it says: any entity found

Comment: I've never heard of 'any entity found' so you should un-accept my answer so other people will come to see if they can answer it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can get right in front of the item frame, type /kill and press space then press tab.
You should see the item frame's uuid pop up. Then execute the command.
The item frame will disappear and a message will say "Killed Item Frame".